# How do I get GraphQL to get live/new data from database without polling?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-server

I have a backend running GraphQL, MongoDB + Mongoose, and Apollo. This application has functionality for user accounts and a friends list. Each user can login to their account and see a list of friends with their current 'status'; If a friend changes their status, I need that change to be reflected on the user's side. An example of this is like facebook's "green dot" on messenger that tells you when one of your friends is online using the application.

I have been searching documentation for GraphQL and have been suggested either Subscriptions or Live Queries. Subscriptions seem to be the majority of suggestions from what I understand, live queries are not officially part of GraphQL or were dropped.

**Does anyone have a solution to getting "live" data with GraphQL/MongoDB that doesn't involve polling for this scenario?**

Comment: The subscription pattern that you mentioned in your question is probably the way to go. Do you have specific reasons why you don't want to use subscriptions? I am not aware of a different solution tailored to what you want to do with GraphQL. Alternatively, you could use bare bone websockets but you would have to implement GraphQL yourself if you were to use that method.

Comment: follow some tutorials, run some ready/forked repo example

Comment: @YvesGurcan No I have nothing wrong with using subscriptions. I just saw something about live queries and it seemed more like what I was looking for, but I couldn't find any good documentation on it and assume it was deprecated or never made it out of beta.

Comment: it's more about possible scaling problems - https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/blob/master/architecture/live-queries.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already seem to have your answer: [subscriptions!](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Subscription)

Using your example, consider two users - mikep17 and mcy. You are mikep17, logged into your application and viewing your list of friends and their statuses. I am your friend, and I log in as you are viewing this list, and you want to see that in your application's UI.

On the frontend, in your application's instance, your application will execute a subscription to some event. Let's call it `friendStatusChange`. Now your application is "listening" for that event in order to respond accordingly. Let's assume that when your application receives the event, it can parse out the information that "I" (mcy) have changed from `offline` => `online` and then use that to add the "green dot" next to my username.

On the backend, your GraphQL server will have code that handles your user functionality - logging in, logging out, etc. It will need to be enhanced to hook into these actions and "publish" the `friendStatusChange` event as applicable.

Now, instead of your client constantly asking (polling) "did a friend's status change? how about now? now?", it can just listen and wait for your server to tap it on the shoulder and say "hey buddy, your friend `mcy`'s status changed".

Comment: Hi mcy, thanks yes I think I will try subscriptions. I guess my confusion is how the subscription will know that data was changed in the database. I have seen other options that use websockets but in all tutorials they are not connected to a database but rather running in memory.  I will try setting the changeStatus mutations to publishers/subscriptions, and the "my friends" array as the subscriber and see if this works.

Comment: The way to know when to publish an event is to hook into the mutation code that causes the db change. You have code that handles when a user logs in, right? (mutations) So in the mutations code you add the publish for an event (e.g., `changeStatus`) with a parameter (e.g., `userId`) and the client registers a subscription listening for the event.

Comment: Hey again @mcy, I just wanted to follow up, and for anyone in the future who searches this: I used a Query and a Subscription, and combined these two things with `SubscribeToMore` in Apollo-React frontend, and merged the new Subscription data with the original Query data.  On the backend, there is a `withFilter` function that is attached to a subscription that lets me check something like `return payload.recieverID === context.recieverID;` to make sure the data is sent to the right 'user'.

Example I found: https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/8-subscriptions/